# How do I compare values of a sublist

Tags: python

I am trying to find the second minimum value in a nested list, where every sublist contains a name and a float value.

I need help with comparing the associated float values if there are any duplicate values.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    list = []
    for _ in range(n):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        list.append([name,score])


listsort = sorted(list,key = lambda x:x[1])
newlist = listsort[1:2]
#if listsort[] 
newlist.sort()
print(newlist)
```

it works fine without duplicate values.

```
Input : 
5
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39
```

Output : `[['Berry', 37.21] ['Harry', 37.21]]`

Comment: So you need help making this work when there are duplicates?  How should it behave under such circumstances?

Comment: As I understand correctly, do you need to return two values in this case, `Berry` and `Tina`?

Comment: Consider in the input the user gives XYZ, 37.21, then the code should return both XYZ and Berry

Comment: Yeah two values but with the same number here Berry - 37.21 and Tina - 37.2 so just Berry

Comment: You need to make a [mcve] and [edit] it in to the question. For example the input process is irrelevant; just give us a value for `list`. BTW, `list` is a bad name since it overwrites the `list` builtin.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a *clear* example input and your desired output from that.

Answer (score 2):

Adapting your code, we can enumerate over the list and check if the float value is equal to `listsort[1][1]` (the 2nd smallest value). If so, return the person and float value.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    list = []
    for _ in range(n):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        list.append([name,score])


listsort = sorted(list,key = lambda x:x[1])
print([listsort[i] for i, x in enumerate(listsort) if x[1] == listsort[1][1]])
```

Input:

```
4
Tom
1
Jeff
2
Bob
2
Henry
3
```

Result:

```py
[['Jeff', 2.0], ['Bob', 2.0]]
```

Comment: your code fails if the input were :4
Tom
1
Jeff
2
Bob
2
Henry
1

Comment: This solves it second_highest = sorted(list(set( score for name , score in listsort)))[1]